# String multiplied by number, need it to return an error

Tags: python

I just realized that in python a string multiplied by a number, just repeats the string multiple times. I need it to return an error saying that's an invalid operation so I can catch it in my code and process some logic.

I have tried using operator.mul but that still results in the same problem.

What am I missing?

EDIT: I could go about checking for *isinstance* but since that's duck typing, I am assuming there must be an easier way

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? Are you trying to process/validate someone else's code?

Comment: `if isinstance(variable, str): raise error` - it is easier way and more readable

Comment: @furas, I guess he doesn't want to check the type of the variable

Comment: @blhsing I am trying to replicate the logic of some formulas from Excel. In Excel, a text multiplied by a number raises an Error and I was trying to do the same.

Comment: @pokfungChan maybe OP doesn't want it but it is more readable method. Other method may only confuse other people and confuseauthor after few months when he forgot what this code should do.

Comment: @Anubhav, Python and Excel are different, full stop. Don't expect one to behave like the other, any more than you'd expect JavaScript and Haskell to behave the same way. If you need non-Python behaviour in Python, find a library that already does it or write your own that manually parses whatever expressions you're supporting and then evaluates them according to your rules.

Comment: Also, I certainly hope you're not using [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=eval#eval) on user-provided code. That would be _incredibly_ insecure.

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of a very stupid way:

Let's say you want to multiply x and y.

```
(x//1) * (y//1) # or you can use / if you also allow floating point numbers
```

this will raise an error when x or y is a string

Comment: It's not stupid if it works! You could also just add 0. Regardless, you want parentheses to force the divisions/additions to be done before the multiplications.

Comment: @kindall, oh yes you are right! Thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 0):

You have not included any code, but I am going to assume that what you are missing is the proper class structure. See below:

```
class MyFloat(object):
  def __init__(self, a):
    self.a = a
  def __mul__(self, other):
    if type(self.a) != type(other.a):
      raise ValueError()
    return self.a*other.a
  def __repr__(self):
    return str(self.a)

a = MyFloat("3")
b = MyFloat(3) 
print(a*b)
```

This will raise the error that you are expecting.